# Purpose of variable

Tags: javascript

```
var ninja = { 
    yell: function yell(n){ 
       return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
    } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Works as we would expect it to!" ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 

var ninja = {};

assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );
```

This code block is taken from John Resig's [JS tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#14). What I'm wondering is, why did he include the second last line? What's the purpose of ninja there?

Comment: Since there is no subsequent code that follows that line and uses the variable, we can only speculate. Try asking John Resig.

Comment: Is he not just clearing `ninja` to show that `samurai.yell(4)` now works regardless of what was originally in the ninja object?

Comment: Perhaps he is suggesting the samurai beats the ninja?

Comment: Yeah, what @Quentin said. My **guess** is that it's there to prove the point that `ninja` is no more (it's overwritten by an empty object, thus `ninja.yell` no longer exists), the function itself does (so `samurai.yell` still makes perfectly sense). But as said, only speculations.

Comment: @DavidStarkey But how can a samurai defeat a ninja when he can't see him?

Comment: @MarkWalters A more pressing question is why a samurai was used instead of a pirate.

Comment: @MarkWalters Never said I agree with it.  Still seems like faulty logic, but free world, eh?

Comment: next time instead of throwing code at people , give some context will you ? you could have put a link to the tutorial itself.

Comment: @ajp15243 now thats just being silly. John Resig is a clever man, I believe, he would have considered every avenue before settling on these variable names

Comment: @MarkWalters The only logical conclusion is that he is unaware of [the war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_and_ninjas).

Comment: @ajp15243 Your comment suddenly makes a of sense. I too was unaware of this. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @MarkWalters Since I was born on [the Day of the Ninja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Burger#Day_of_the_Ninja), my loyalties are obvious. Although looting booty is often rather fun :P.

Comment: @mpm I did give context. I'm not sure how saying "This code block is taken from John Resig's JS tutorial," and describing my confusion with regard to the code is not sufficient explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tutorial is showing that removing references to objects does not delete the object itself.

`ninja` which contained a function `yell` is shown to have the reference to that function removed, while the reference still exists in a different variable, `samurai`. Calling the function through `samurai` even though `ninja` no longer has it shows that objects persist past the variable referencing them no longer doing so.

Comment: Exactly what I meant, just described in more detail

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Some things aren't obvious when learning the advanced sections of a language, especially without any explicit explanation as to the importance of the sections. It's unclear to me why this question received so many down votes :/

Comment: @NimaVaziri It is a 'not constructive' question and not fit for being on Stack Overflow, because it is an open-ended question - it is asking 'what is the intent of person X?' which can't be answered definitively.

Answer (score 2):

It's to demonstrate that even though the `ninja` object is no longer referenced, you can still call it and the recursion will work.

Of course, there's two major problems I have with that tutorial.

1. You can use `arguments.callee` to call the current function, instead of having to name the function itself. Especially useful for anonymous functions. Deprecated in strict mode, but ask me if I give a rat's arse.
2. You don't need recursion for this function anyway:

   ```
   return "hiy"+new Array(n+1).join("a");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice the previous code: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#13

It shows that anonymous functions disappear once the parent object has been cleared.

#14 shows that if you give the anonymous function a name, it would still be able to reference it if set to another variable.