# Javascript-scope of object method

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, anonymous

```
var ninja = {
  yell: function yellaaa(n){
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
  }
};

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = null;
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );
```

I would like to ask, why samurai.yell can still be called after ninja.null is being deleted?
Does this mean by giving object method a name, the copy becomes a "deep copy", while anonymous function will only conduct a "shallow copy"?

Thanks

Comment: seems exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986234/purpose-of-variable

Comment: `The tutorial is showing that removing references to objects does not delete the object itself.` as Cherniv mentioned answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986234/purpose-of-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are objects as well. 
While Ninja creates yell function object, later in code you reference it by Samurai. So now you have 2 references to the same (function) object. Later you "delete" Ninja (which is one of those 2 referees) but you still hold reference in Samurai.